# How to debug "undefined reference" in my C unload function?

Tags: c, cs50

This is the unload function code.

```
bool unload(void)
{
    void release_nodes (node* node_to_free);

    //looking for children node to free
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (node_to_free -> children[i])
        {
            release_nodes (node_to_free -> children[i]);
        }
    }

    free (node_to_free);

    return false;
}
```

This is the response I receive when I compile.

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror   -c -o speller.o speller.c
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror   -c -o dictionary.o dictionary.c
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -o speller speller.o dictionary.o 
dictionary.o: In function `unload':
/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset5/speller/dictionary.c:170: undefined reference to `release_nodes'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [speller] Error 1
```

Comment: And where is `release_nodes` defined? In which source file? Do you build with that file?

Comment: Also, declaring a function inside another function is probably not what you want (although that's not incorrect). You'd better move the declaration in some header file.

Comment: It looks like this is supposed to be the definition of the `release_nodes()` function. `unload()` should be a separate function, which calls `release_nodes()` with the root node as the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be defining the `release_nodes()` function, not declaring it.

```
void release_nodes (node* node_to_free) {
    //looking for children node to free
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (node_to_free -> children[i])
        {
            release_nodes (node_to_free -> children[i]);
        }
    }

    free (node_to_free);
}
```

Then you call this function from `unload()`:

```
bool unload(void) {
    if (root_node) {
        release_nodes(root_node);
        root_node = NULL;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Replace `root_node` with the name of the global variable that holds the root of your tree.

Comment: Right, got them confused. Although why it would always return `false` is a mystery.

Comment: Thanks to you all. The problem has been taken care of.